# Dynamic string creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I am trying to build a string in rails.  The string should be in the format:

```
"| :lat , :long | :lat , :long |"
```

where :lat and :long are latitude and longitude values respectively.

I have tried:

```
      <% coords.each_with_index do | i | %>
          <% #{pathString} = #{pathString} | #{coords[i].lat} , #{coords[i].long} %>
      <% end %>
```

The coords variable has the format:

```
{lat: value, lng: value}...
```

I made coords with:

```
<% coords = job.polygon.coordinates.map {|model| { lat: model.latitude, lng: model.longitude}} %>
```

I am simply not sure how to build the pathString.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: coords is an array of hashes?

Comment: I created coords with `<% coords = job.polygon.coordinates.map {|model| { lat: model.latitude, lng: model.longitude}} %>`

Comment: Your question is not clear, what are you trying to achieve here? Why are you creating those strings in the view?

Comment: I need to create a URL that will be in a partial.  The string will form part of a url.  The URL returns a map with a polygon on it.

Comment: But you can create the string in controller as well right?

Comment: Can I pass it to a partial?  If the partial is called _details.html.erb can I just do `def details ... end`?

Comment: Can you add code where you are calling the partial?

Comment: I am calling the partial from a view

Comment: Yes, that one only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want to do it from view,

```
<%
  path_string = "|"
  coords.each do |coord|
    path_string << " #{coord[:lat]} , #{coord[:lng]} |"
  end 
%>
```

`path_string` is the string you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Will probably do it from the controller like you suggested, but that was what I was looking for.  Cheers.

Comment: Please do not create a new instance of `String` for each subsequent `coords`. Also, ruby is not php: `coords.each_with_object("") { |coord, path| path << " #{coord[:lat]} , #{coord[:lng]} |" }` or, even better: `coords.map { |coord| [coord[:lat]} , coord[:lng]].join(', ')}.join(' | ')`.

Comment: Right, the best way to do that is to do it in the controller using `map`, I will update the answer. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You can also use `'%{lat}, %{lng}' % coord` to build the lat-long pairs.